# React-Query useMutation: is not assignable to parameter of type "mutationkey"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I have api call that looks like

```
const getMutationService = () => {
  return {
    createMeme: async (
      _private: string,
      templateId: string,
      file: Blob,
      memeText?: string,
      title?: string,
      tags?: Array<string>,
    ): Promise<MemeCreateMemeResponse | undefined> => {
      return await memeApi.memePost({
        _private,
        templateId,
        file,
        memeText,
        title,
        tags,
      });
    },
  };
};
```

and I am calling this in another hook like

```
const mutationService = getMutationService();



 const { mutate: createMeme } = useMutation(mutationService.createMeme);
```

Its throwing an error of

> Argument of type '(_private: string, templateId: string, file: Blob, memeText?: string, title?: string, tags?: Array) => Promise<MemeCreateMemeResponse | undefined>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MutationKey'.

I have done other mutation calls with the same pattern. Why is this one throwing this mutation key error?
Confused

Answer (score 30):

`useMutation` can only accept one parameter. If you need multiple parameters, please use an object.

Comment: An example would be appreciated.

Comment: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/mastering-mutations-in-react-query#mutations-only-take-one-argument-for-variables

Answer (score 1):

Also, the `useMutation` hook accepts an **async** function.

```js
const foo = async (param: Param) => { ... };
// Optional: You can also specify the return type
const foo = async (param: Param): Promise<Return> => { ... };

useMutation(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

What the other answers do not mention is that mutationFn also takes only 1 param not just useMutation.
example -

```
useMutation({
mutationKey : 'abc',
mutationFn : ({a, b ,c}) => fetch(../)
})
```

**WRONG -> mutationFn : (a,b,c) => fetch**

**CORRECT -> mutationFn : ({a, b ,c}) => fetch(../)**